# How to get a slide element in an event, in Slick Carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

Slick Carousel: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

How can I get the element of the slide in an event?
For example:

```
   .on('afterChange', function (slick, currentSlide)
   {
      var currentSlideElement = //Get current slide element here
   });
```

The first argument seems to be the `event` object, but its `target` (or `currentTarget`) is always the slides container, and second argument seems to be the slick object....

Answer (score 21):

you need to include the first argument "event" like this

```
$('.your-element').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
  console.log(currentSlide);
});
```

or else your "currentSlide" argument will be "slick"

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me towards the right direction. ```currentSlide``` returns a number, and then I can select the element via the ```data-slick-index``` attribute, e.g. ```$("[data-slick-index='"+currentSlide+"']);```.

Comment: Is there a way to access previous slide on `afterChange` event?

Comment: @max: `$("[data-slick-index='"+(currentSlide-1)+"']);`

Comment: @YuvalA that won't work when moving back a slide or when using slickGoTo

Answer (score 12):

To get the DOM element on 'afterChange' event:

```
$('.your-element').on('afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide) {
    var elt = slick.$slides.get(currentSlide);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
// Get the current slide
var currentSlide = $('.your-element').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
```

Source: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick

Comment: Just in case it can save someone some time, this returns the index of the current slide, but if you want the current slide as a jQuery object you can just use `var currentSlide = $( '.your-element .slick-current' );`

Answer (score 0):

The 'currentSlide' parameter does **not** work as expected if you are displaying multiple slides at once.

The way I have found in this instance is with the 'slick-current' class that gets added to the current slide.

e.g. where `slider` is the HTML element wrapper for you carousel:

```
$('.your-element').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentPage){
    var currentIndex = parseInt(slider.querySelector('.slick-current').getAttribute('data-slick-index'));
});
```